# I can't see changes when updating css files for Magento 1.5 although I have cleared the cache

Tags: magento

I edited and uploaded a css file to my Magento 1.5 site. I refreshed the cache and also refreshed the browser cache but I could see any changes reflected to the site. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check that Magento is sending the correct CSS file from the correct theme? 
This might seem like a basic mistake, but it happens more often than you think especially if you have multiple design/theme folders. View source of HTML and just make sure that the page is using the CSS file you modified.

If magento is not sending the correct CSS, 
check in admin -> System -> Design ->  Themes -> Skin or your phtml code.
When you include your CSS file from PHP(template) code, make sure you use

```
href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/fileName.css')?>"
```

Also, you can clear cache directly by deleting folders in from magento/var/cache/

If Magento is sending the correct CSS file, then the last thing you can do is adding a version name to the CSS from the layout or from phtml code. Just convert fileName.css to fileName.css?v=01 or something, then the browser will download the latest change.

Hope one of these will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running some caching script on a load balancer (eg varnish) make sure you restart that too or run the clear cache comment there.

Magento also has a Flush Javascript/CSS cache, have you tried clearing that.

If this all doesn't apply/work just delete everything in the /var/cache/ folder ;)