# Magento css changes not showing

Tags: html, css, magento, caching

I made some css changes to my custom css file and uploaded the css file. However the changes are not shown. I have tried all of following:

```
remove var/cache/*
flush js/css cache from magento admin
clear browser cache
flush siteground cache
```

I even tried removing the css file and then access it from url `URL`, the old file content still shows but the css effects were gone on front UI.

what could be wrong.....

Comment: check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572673/i-cant-see-changes-when-updating-css-files-for-magento-1-5-although-i-have-clea)

Comment: thanks Jatin for the pointer, I had to add the version paramenter '?v=01'to url to make it work: href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/wide_menu.css'); ?>?v=01"

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your browser is still caching your CSS files. One way to check if it is indeed the browser and not say accidentally editing the wrong CSS file is by enabling and disabling the CSS file merge. By doing so you are forcing the browser to fetch for a whole new file - essentially bypassing caching.

You may also want to take a look at our CSS/JS Versioning extension which includes automatic refresh of the file name hash based on CSS/JS file timestamps (sensitive to editing and changes) http://extensions.activo.com/css-and-javascript-versioning.html